# Set maximum timeout for a step in GCP workflows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-workflows

I have a workflow that calls some cloud functions, the timeout of the cloud function in question is 400 secs. When calling this function in google workflows it returns a timeout error (I saw that the default workflow timeout is 300 secs)

How can I change that ?

```
request timed out
in step "getMedicineUserTransformations", routine "main", line: 51
{
  "message": "request timed out",
  "tags": [
    "TimeoutError",
    "OSError"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have an HTTP function and you are using workflows `http` lib to call it. In this case **the default timeout is 300s but you can increase it up to 1800s** as stated in the documentation.

> The request timeout, in seconds (default: 300.0). If the request takes longer than the timeout, a TimeoutError is raised. The maximum allowed timeout is 1800 seconds.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/get

And you can increase it by setting the `timeout` arg under args of your `call: http.<method>`

More details in the doc here : https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/http-requests#invoke-endpoint

Answer (score 1):

When the specified [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/get) is reached before the response is received that time  “TimeoutError” will be triggered.So [increase the timeout](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/http-requests#invoke-endpoint)